# JUnit AssertEquals fails

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a code which for the following

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

System.out.println("obj1 name = " + obj1.getName());
System.out.println("obj1 value = " + (obj1.getvalue() == null ? "null" : "not null"));
System.out.println("obj2 name = " + obj2.getName());
System.out.println("obj2 value = " + (obj2.getvalue() == null ? "null" : "not null"));

assertEquals(obj2, obj1);
```

yields

```
obj1 name = DC2
obj1 value = null
obj2 name = DC2
obj2 value = null

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :com.gms.contract.myClass.inventory.MyClass@795ce9b5
Actual   :com.gms.contract.myClass.inventory.MyClass@280cb0b4
```

Isn't assertEquals suppose to compare by value??
It looks to me that it compares objects address.
But maybe I am wrong?...

Comment: You need to override `equals` in `MyClass`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Isn't assertEquals suppose to compare by value??

No, it's supposed to compare using the `equals` method.

You need to override `equals` in `MyClass` (and override `hashCode` correspondingly).

> It looks to me that it compares objects address.

No, that's simply the result of invoking `toString()` on `MyClass`, without you having overridden it. If you want something more meaningful to be shown, override `toString()` too.